# javascript refresh current page with fragment

Tags: javascript, refresh, fragment

How do I refresh the current page with a fragment?

If a page url is like: `localhost/test#1` do `<a href="http://localhost/test#2">` how do I refresh the current page?

```
location.reload(true)

window.location.reload()
```

These 2 methods will all reload the page still to `localhost/test#1`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location.hash` ?

```
setTimeout((
    function(){
        window.location.hash = '#2';
    }
), 2000);

// so: <a href="http://localhost/test#2" onclick="window.location.hash='#2';window.location.reload();">aaa</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to take a closer look at the **hashchange** event. Fortunately there is a  nice jQuery plugin called BBQ.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

**#** urls works on client only. part after # does not send to server

Answer (score 0):

You can use Url Rewriting

In your .htaccess file add those lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

In your page test/index.php you can use the link(without the #):

```
<a href="2">Page 2</a>
```

It will store it in $_GET['p'] (in the example the target is php)

Find the rewriting rule that answer your needs.